# Checking specific key/value exists in custom sequences

Tags: scala

I am mind boggled right now as to how to get this to work.

I have a case class such as:

```
case class Visitors(start: Int, end: Int, visitor_num: Int)
```

Now say I create two separate Sequences of type Visitors:

```
val visitors_A = Seq(Visitors(start = 1, end = 1, visitor_num = 2),Visitors(start = 2, end = 2, visitor_num = 129),Visitors(start = 3, end = 3, visitor_num = 90))

val visitors_B = Seq(Visitors(start = 1, end = 1, visitor_num = 0),Visitors(start = 2, end = 2, visitor_num = 0))
```

I want to create a separate Visitors Sequence that will output a Sequence of Visitors that have the same start times from both visitors_A and visitors_B,
output example should be:

```
visitors_Same =  Seq(Visitors(start = 1, end = 1, visitor_num = 2),Visitors(start = 2, end = 2, visitor_num = 129)
```

It should check whether start times are in both of the Sequences, if they are, grab the Sequence values from visitors_A and append it to the list.

What confuses me is that I am working with a "custom" type of Visitor, and I cannot seem to be able to run intersect or contains function calls for visitor_a in visitor_b, I understand I probably need to check whether start value from A exists in B and then map (?) the output to a new sequence of type Visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a one liner (but probably very inefficient) here it is:

```
val r1 = visitors_A.filter(va => visitors_B.exists(vb => vb.start == va.start))
```

You can gain a bit more speed if you convert `visitors_B` to a `Map` first (logically the map is `start -> visitor`):

```
val vbm = visitors_B.map(vb => (vb.start, vb)).toMap
val r2 = visitors_A.filter(va => vbm.contains(va.start))
```

**Edit**

Actually since values in the `Map` are not used at all, you can use `Set` instead which will be a bit more efficient than `Map`:

```
val vbs = visitors_B.map(vb => vb.start).toSet
val r3 = visitors_A.filter(va => vbs.contains(va.start))
```

Comment: This is it, man, scala is so damn difficult to wrap my head around.

Comment: @user3674993, well this is actually relatively easy. I'm not sure why you find it difficult but you probably should just solve a few more similar training problems. The logic of the one-liner is following: first let's build a check for a fixed `va` if it should be in the result. It is easy, just check if `visitors_B` contains a record with the same `start`. Now when we have such a check (aka predicate) just use it in a `filter` call. The `Map`-based solution is a trick to speed-up the predicate check by first building an efficient data-structure that can answer the question of `exists` kind.

Comment: I guess mean the logic of it is not difficult but implementation of calling functions within functions is just throwing me off quite a bit.

Comment: @user3674993, I know the only way to get around it: just get a bit more experience. It is not that hard really.

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, its always easier with experience. I just hate it when I cannot think of a solution myself :(

Comment: @user3674993, one exercise I can suggest is try implementing various methods of the collections API (of a `Seq` or of a `List`) using other methods. Forget about all the fancy stuff with `implicit`s and mapping to different types collections, it is OK to just always return `List`. The point is that there is really only a very small "core" of just a few methods and all the others can be implemented in terms of them. For example `intersect` as you see can be implemented as `filter` + `contains` but you can go much deeper. For example you can implement `filter` using `fold`

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going through the collections API now.